# Protecting critical code from being called again

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, locking, blocking, grand-central-dispatch

I need to protect a critical area of my code, which is multi-threaded. I want to prevent it from being called multiple times before the other thread is finished. This is what I am working with:

```
- (void) filterAllEventsIntoDictionary{

    // start critical area
    if (self.sortedKeys.count != 0) {
        [self.sortedKeys removeAllObjects];
    }
    dispatch_async(self.filterMainQueue, ^{

        [self internal_filterAllEventsIntoDictionary]; 

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Since the `internal_filterAllEventsIntoDictionary` method also accesses `self.sortedKeys`, if this code is called twice, it crashes because of `removeAllObjects` at the start.

I still need to call the `internal...` method in another thread since I don't want to block the UI. So what's the best way to block on the start of this method while the `dispatch_async` call is still not finished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I am far from being a concurrency expert, it sounds to me like you need a lock on your `sortedKeys` object. If you used a traditional lock, though, you'd end up blocking the main thread.

The recommended replacement for locks in the world of Grand Central Dispatch is to put critical sections of code on a serial queue. See ["Eliminating Lock-Based Code"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) in the Concurrency Programming Guide.

If you put the `[self.sortedKeys removeAllObjects];` call onto the same queue that the block with the `internal...` call is scheduled on, you guarantee that it won't happen until after that block completes:

```
// start critical area
dispatch_async(self.filterMainQueue, ^{
    if (self.sortedKeys.count != 0) {
        [self.sortedKeys removeAllObjects];
    }
});
```

This assumes that `filterMainQueue` is *serial*. Using `dispatch_async` for the critical section ensures that the main thread will not be blocked. Also note the warning in ["Dispatch Queues and Thread Safety"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW28):

> Do not call the `dispatch_sync` function from a task that is executing on the same queue that you pass to your function call. Doing so will deadlock the queue.

Although this will only be an issue if the `internal...` method does something that causes this method to be called again.